# How do I reference a schema defined in the same WSDL file?

Tags: xsd

I got a wsdl file that defines two schemas for the same namespace, like this:

```
<wsdl:types>
   <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://example.com/payments"
                attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified"
                targetNamespace="http://example.com/payments">
        <xsd:complexType name="TestType">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="Version" type="xsd:string" />
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:schema>
    <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://example.com/payments"
                attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified"
                targetNamespace="http://example.com/payments">
        <xsd:element name="TestRequest">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="Header" type="TestType"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
```

Sure enough `TestType` can't be referenced from the `TestRequest`. I've found several [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20760462/xsd-reference-a-type-defined-within-the-same-file) that show how you'd do that for different files via a `xsd:include` (as I'm using the same `targetNamespace`), but I'm at a loss at how to give the `schemaLocation` to include?

Note that whether not this is something I should be doing is not the question. I *know* the issue disappears if I move the element definitions into the same schema definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For XSDs embedded inside WSDLs, things are different than what you've looked at,  considering the answer you've linked in your question.

Short answers:

- one **cannot create xsd:include references** between schemas nested within a WSDL's types section.
- xsd:import is supported by most WSDL processors. However, you **do not** supply the schemaLocation attribute. In effect, it creates a dangling schema reference, with the WSDL itself acting similarly to an XML catalog.

There is no standard way to point at schemas inside arbitrary XML files (other then the .XSD file format, where the whole file is for one schema only). Of course, XPointer or something similar might've worked; but nobody seems to have implement a solution for this in an XSD or WSDL processor.

The fact that your schemas with the same namespace are not working shows a limitation in the implementation of your WSDL processor. There should be no reason to have dangling imports resolved, but not schemas **with a target namespace**. The reason of the latter highlight is that schemas with no namespace can be included and/or imported, which would cause ambiguity.

Comment: Actually, the solution with XPointer is usually to use a URIResolver to be used by the XSD processor. The XSD processor may not natively support XPointer, but in a URIResolver you can do this in whatever way you please (assuming your system allows you to add URIResolver, and you have access to an XPointer implementation).

Comment: So what you're saying is that CXF (which is what is used here) should be able to make sense of the schema?

Comment: @mabi, yes, it should. If it doesn't, just refactor it and move on - unless you have time to fix it yourself since the code is open source :).

Comment: Yeah, actually Abel's idea of using XSLT to refactor the offending WSDL into something digestible (and mid-term cluing in the WSDL provider) is probably what I'm gonna do.

Comment: @mabi, I would be interested to know if the "offending" WSDL was manually edited or generated by a tool (in which case I would guess it is not a mainstream product). Also, try to run it through a WS-I compliance tool, see if it spots anything that might give you more reason to have it refactored for you.

Comment: I pulled this from a customer and my *guess* is that their development group haphazardly glued this together from different xsds and went with it on the basis that "hey, this works with Axis1" (and it does!)

Answer (score 1):

WSDL is itself not the XSD Schema language, so to reference it from your XSD file through `xs:include` you will have to get rid of the surrounding `wsdl:types` and you will have to store both schema's in separate files (or, since they are in the same namespace anyway, simply remove the extra `xsd:schema` element, but not its contents).

You could do that with a trivial XSLT (root note removed for brevity, make sure to declare the relevant namespaces):

```
<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="wsdl:types">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="xsd:schema[1]" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="xsd:schema">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
        <xsl:apply-templates />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::xsd:schema/*" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

If this is a one-off task, then you can simply run this once against your WSDL, save the results and reference them by relative file URI. If you need to do this more often, you should probably automate this.

Comment: Thanks for your solution! It's very helpful in the short-term. I marked Petru's answer as accepted because the answer is basically "you can't", which he spelled out explicitly. But you get +1 for the workaround nevertheless. Thanks!